# Dropddown menu top-down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I wonder how I can get this dropdown menu open its childrens from top to bottom instead from left to right? Having the li's inside the ul's open up horizontally instead of vertically.

Also I want to make a specific list visible and not hidden like all others. I tried to label this ul with a own class named 'last' and making it visible with CSS... I have no experience using CSS.

Thank you very much.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.last {
  visibility: visible;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container>ul {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #224490;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 250px;
  top: 0;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="lists">
    <li class="parent">str1str2str34
      <ul class="child">
        <li class="parent">A
          <ul class="child">
            <li>a11</li>
            <li>a12 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">B
          <ul class="child">
            <li class="parent">B1
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b11</li>
                <li>b12 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B2
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b21 </li>
                <li>22 </li>
                <li>23 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B3
              <ul class="child">
                <li class="parent">B31
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b31</li>
                    <li>b32 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">B32
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b41</li>
                    <li>b42</li>
                    <li>b43 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">C
          <ul class="child">
            <li>c11</li>
            <li class="parent">c12
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b41</li>
                <li>b42</li>
                <li>b43 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>c13 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the display in `ul li` from `block` to `inline-block`. In order to position correctly, I have commented out the `left: 250px;` and `top: 0;` in `ul li:hover>ul`

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* Change form block to inline-block */
  position: relative;
  background-color: #224490;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  /* left: 250px; 
     top: 0; */
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.last {
  visibility: visible;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0; /* Edit 1: childrens right beneath the parent */
}

.container>ul {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* Change form block to inline-block */
  position: relative;
  background-color: #224490;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  /* left: 250px; 
     top: 0; */
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul class="lists">
    <li class="parent">str1str2str34
      <ul class="child">
        <li class="parent">A
          <ul class="child">
            <li>a11</li>
            <li>a12 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">B
          <ul class="child">
            <li class="parent">B1
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b11</li>
                <li>b12 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B2
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b21 </li>
                <li>22 </li>
                <li>23 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B3
              <ul class="child">
                <li class="parent">B31
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b31</li>
                    <li>b32 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">B32
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b41</li>
                    <li>b42</li>
                    <li>b43 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">C
          <ul class="child">
            <li>c11</li>
            <li class="parent">c12
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b41</li>
                <li>b42</li>
                <li>b43 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>c13 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Update: To have all children visible all the time

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.last {
  visibility: visible;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0; /* Edit 1: childrens right beneath the parent */
}

.container>ul {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* Change form block to inline-block */
  position: relative;
  background-color: #224490;
}

/* Comment out hover function */
/*
ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  /* left: 250px; 
     top: 0; 
}
*/
/* Update to always show the children */
ul ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li {
  background-color: white;
}
/* Flexbox to configure A B C into column */
ul.lists > li > ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul class="lists">
    <li class="parent">str1str2str34
      <ul class="child">
        <li class="parent">A
          <ul class="child">
            <li>a11</li>
            <li>a12 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">B
          <ul class="child">
            <li class="parent">B1
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b11</li>
                <li>b12 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B2
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b21 </li>
                <li>22 </li>
                <li>23 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B3
              <ul class="child">
                <li class="parent">B31
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b31</li>
                    <li>b32 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">B32
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b41</li>
                    <li>b42</li>
                    <li>b43 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">C
          <ul class="child">
            <li>c11</li>
            <li class="parent">c12
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b41</li>
                <li>b42</li>
                <li>b43 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>c13 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Based on our discussion, I have implemented the code where open up the child all from the absolute left and not from below the parent li but instead under the FIRST parent li. But, the limitation is to have a fixed width for each li. It is expected that the ABC list will cover the D list when hovering over it.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.last {
  visibility: visible;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0;  /* Edit 1: childrens right beneath the parent */
}

.container>ul {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;  /* height: 100vh; */
}

ul.lists>li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;  /* Change form block to inline-block */
  background-color: #224490;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  /* left: 250px;
    top: 0; */
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%; */
}

ul li {
  background-color: white;
}

ul>li {
  position: absolute;
}

ul>li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 150px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 200px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(2)>ul {
  left: -50px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(3)>ul {
  left: -100px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(4)>ul {
  left: -150px;
}

ul>li:nth-child(5)>ul {
  left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul class="lists">
    <li class="parent">str1str2str34
      <ul class="child">
        <li class="parent">A
          <ul class="child">
            <li>a11</li>
            <li>a12 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">B
          <ul class="child">
            <li class="parent">B1
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b11</li>
                <li>b12 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B2
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b21 </li>
                <li>22 </li>
                <li>23 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">B3
              <ul class="child">
                <li class="parent">B31
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b31</li>
                    <li>b32 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">B32
                  <ul class="child">
                    <li>b41</li>
                    <li>b42</li>
                    <li>b43 </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">C
          <ul class="child">
            <li>c11</li>
            <li class="parent">c12
              <ul class="child">
                <li>b41</li>
                <li>b42</li>
                <li>b43 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>c13 </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li> D1 </li>
    <li> D2 </li>
    <li> D3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I need the childrens right beneath the parent. Right now hey are all slightly shifted to the right. Can I get them straight down?

What about my second question that I like to have any children to be visible all time?

Comment: I have edited and added comment to have the childrens right beneath the parent. There are multiple levels of children, do you want to display all of them? with current design it is impossible because the display will be overlapping.

Comment: I have updated the second code snippet to have all children visible all the time. But, I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you
To the first. Thats better but now now everything is no pad to the left with no margin which looks very ugly. Can I have a margin of all to the whole window?

To the 2) I wanted that eg this last ul is visibile while all others are like right now (hidden with hover):

<ul class="child">
                    <li>b41</li>
                    <li>b42</li>
                    <li>b43 </li>
                  </ul>

Comment: But actually what I really like is just a rowise list or anything else but it has to be a row right after the dropdown menu. This shall show some static information visible whole time

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand `Can I have a margin of all to the whole window?`. For the 2, I am not able to do that. I don't think that when the parent is display:none and the children want to display is possible,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215369/discussion-between-chris-hum-and-yinsweet).

Comment: Hey, I juts saw your edits. That is nice. Almost what I want. But the D list disappears when hovering over ABC etc. I just only would like to have the D list still be there. Thankyou anyway!

Comment: @Chrishum glad to help